# If $A(x)$ is 1-periodic and $\frac{A''(x)}{A(x)} = C$, then $C=-4\pi^2 n^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

This might be a trivial question but I forgot my differential equation. Anyway, I am trying to solve the heat equation on circle.

> Given that $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
>
> where $u(x,t)$ is 1-periodic in $x$. Solve for $u$.

The Fourier Analysis by Stein starts by assuming $u(x,t)$ is in form of $u(x,t) = A(x)B(t)$. Suppose this actually works, we end up with

$$\frac{B'(t)}{B(t)} = \frac{A''(x)}{A(x)}$$

I understand that this would imply both sides equal to a constant say $\lambda$. But I don't understand the following

> ...Since $A(x)$ is periodic of period $1$, we see that the only possibility is $\lambda = -4\pi^2 n^2$ ...

From $A''(x) = \lambda A(x)$, I get $A(x) = c_1 e^{\sqrt{\lambda} x} + c_2 e^{-\sqrt{\lambda} x}$, but I don't know what I should do after that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{A''(x)}{A(x)}=\lambda \Rightarrow A(x) = C\sin(\sqrt{-\lambda } x + \phi)$$
Because $A(x)$ should be 1-periodic $$\sqrt{- \lambda}=2\pi n \Rightarrow \lambda=-4\pi^2 n^2.$$

Comment: Would you mind elaborate on your first line? I have updated my question.

Comment: Yes, but your result is definitely not periodic for any positive $\lambda.$ So the next step is to investigate non-positive (negative or zero) lambdas which lead to an equation like $A''(x) = -(-\lambda) A(x),\ \lambda < 0$ which has sine/cosine solutions.

Comment: I see. I forgot that $\lambda$ could be negative. Thanks.

Comment: @a-rodin why is the result definitely not periodic for any positive $\lambda$?

Comment: @takecare For any positive $\lambda$ the solution would be something like $C_1 e^{\sqrt{\lambda} x} + C_2 e^{-\sqrt{\lambda} x}$ and it is not periodic for any non-zero $\lambda.$ The latest statement is true because $e^{\alpha (x + T)} - e^{\alpha x} = e^{\alpha x} \left(e^{\alpha T} - 1\right) \neq 0\ \forall T \neq 0\ \forall \alpha \neq 0\ \forall x$.

Answer (score 1):

In problems of this type, you need two conditions. In your case, you probably want
$$
            A(0)=A(1),\;\;\; A'(0)=A'(1). \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
Conditions such as $A(0)=A(1), \; A'(0)=-A'(1)$ are equally valid, and could still be considered periodic because $A(0)=A(1)$. Simple periodicity is not sufficient to pin down the eigenvalues. In the case of $(\dagger)$, and assuming $\lambda \ne 0$,
$$
   c_1 + c_2 = c_1e^{\sqrt{\lambda}}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}} \\
   c_1-c_2 = c_1e^{\sqrt{\lambda}}-c_2e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}} \\
   \implies c_1(1-e^{\sqrt{\lambda}})=0,\;\; c_2(1-e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}})=0.
$$
That's how you end up with $\sqrt{\lambda}=2\pi i n$ or $\lambda=-4\pi^2n^2$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$. The eigenspaces are two dimensional, except for $n=0$.

The case where $A(0)=A(1),\; A'(0)=-A'(1)$ gives eigenvalues $\lambda=-\pi^2n^2$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$ with eigenfunctions
$$
           1,\sin(\pi x),\cos(2\pi x),\sin(3\pi x),\cos(4\pi x),\cdots.
$$
The eigenspaces are one-dimensional.